# Index column in sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I'm trying to create an Index column in sheets. I have put the number 1 In cell A2, and I have placed an array formula in A3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ISBLANK(B3:B),"",+A2+1))
```

However this does not produce a sequential list (eg 1,2,3) as I had hoped. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in A2. It uses Row to get the number:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",ROW($B$2:$B)-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), ROW(A1:A), ))
```

[image]